# ASP Classic - Data type mismatch error

Tags: asp-classic

I'm trying to make an ID (primary key and autoincrement) from the MS Access database to be used as a login pass. But I'm receiving this error:

> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80040e07'
>
> [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Data type mismatch in criteria expression.

And here is my code:

```
con.open "DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ="& Server.MapPath("db.mdb") &""
sql="SELECT * FROM tblLogin WHERE ID='" & request.form("id") & "';"

rs.CursorType=2

rs.Open sql,con

if rs.bof then
   response.redirect "loginpage.asp?msg=ID does not exist."
else
   response.redirect "adminpage.asp"
end if
```

Please correct me if I'm missing something or any solutions that you recommend.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It look alike you are sending ID as a string. Should it be an int? If so drop the apostrophe's around it.

Comment: Oh thanks. I already removed the quotation marks and I received this error: **[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Driver's SQLSetConnectAttr failed**. Any solutions?

Comment: Can I see your sql= line of code

Comment: this one? `sql="SELECT * FROM tblLogin WHERE ID='" & request.form(id) & "';"
`

Comment: Try it like this and see what happens...

sql="SELECT * FROM tblLogin WHERE ID=" & request.form("id")

Comment: it always falls on if rs.bof

Comment: Are you getting a new error now, though?

Comment: What? Is it redirecting to the admin page and you expect it to go to the login page?

Comment: I think not. either wrong or correct id I input still falling to the if condition

Comment: bof and eof are true if no data is found (empty recordset). better try if rs.recordcount > 0

Comment: just use `If Not rs.EOF`

Answer (score 5):

Change:

```
sql="SELECT * FROM tblLogin WHERE ID='" & request.form("id") & "';"
```

to

```
sql="SELECT * FROM tblLogin WHERE ID=" & request.form("id")
```

Then check like this:

```
If rs.EOF then
   response.redirect "loginpage.asp?msg=ID does not exist."
else
   response.redirect "adminpage.asp"
end if
```

Answer (score 0):

Check 3 things:

1. make sure the form in previous page is submitted by POST method not GET.
2. remove single quote around the id as it is not a string (if ID column is integer) (@meda answer)
3. use `if not rs.eof` instead of `if not rs.bof`

And a security warning besides of your question:

before redirecting to admin page, undoubtedly you need some logic to set session or cookie to determine if real admin is going to target page. it seems that your admin page has no logic to check if user is coming from login page or coming there suddenly!